# Fundamental of Python - Return Value

Tags: python, return-value

[Attached picture related to return value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elXw3.png)

In the attached picture, I am wondering why there are two results? Is it due to the def function derive one and the print function derive another one? Thank you!

Comment: Please include the code in the text of your question. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: In Python, all functions either return an object (`None` by default) or raise an exception.  Printing is a side effect intended for the user.  It is not the same as a returned object used by the program and the user.  Design functions with purpose centered on what objects they return.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a function automatically returns *None*:

```
def f():
    pass

>>> print(f())
None
```

You can, of course, specify other return values:

```
def f():
    return 42

>>> print(f())
42
```

In your example, the function prints a value and returns *None*.  The second print then displays the *None*.  **There are two prints -- that is why you see two values printed.**

Comment: indeed. To clarify. Your function doesn't return anything (i.e it returns None by default). Thus your print(half_value(42)) first exectus half_value(42) which prints 21.0 and then executes print on the return value of half_value which is None